# Parsing a range of time in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So, I am trying to parse a range of numbers in a cell in Excel. For example "5-C" is indicative of 5 to close, close is 10PM but runs to 11PM so this shift would be a total of 6 hours. The dash is the delimiter between time A and time B. So that is my convention. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I know how to code C# so I was looking into writing a macro in C# to do the parsing. However, I found that Excel does not support this? Any help would be appreciated. The purpose of this is for weekly scheduling. Thanks.

Comment: First you'll need to translate your method of time storage into something Excel can understand as a time.  Search for information as to how Excel stores and displays date/time.  You could do this with either formulas or a VBA macro.

Comment: Excel can't run C#, but C# can run Excel :] msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx. Seems like you can just use an Excel formula for this, but it is not completely clear what your question is and what the input and desired output is. For example, Excel formula like `=11-SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-C","")` results in 6 if `A1` contains just `5-C`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first step is to split the string at the dash. Then you can handle the numeric part and the "C" with your specific logic.

You can find the dash with `InStr` and then split your string. In the following example the function will return you the first part (Time A) of the input string. It will also cut the original string leaving the second part after the dash (Time B).

```
Private Function Split(org as String, delimiter As String) as String
   Dim break as Integer
   break = InStr(1, org, delimiter, vbTextCompare)
   TimeA = Left(org, break-1)
   TimeB = Mid(org, break+1)
End Function
```